# Как с помощью алгоритмов nlp сгенерировать текст на основании нескольких inputs?

Tags: nlp, gpt, nlg

Всем привет,
Буду благодарен на любые советы в этом направлении.

У меня стоит задача генерации е-мейлов исходя из входящих данных.
Вот пример входящих данных и сгенерированых емейлов: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O2EG39_a9oMP34kffNnturm6oKTvMk-YUT1H6y3UYqE/edit#gid=0

Колонки

- `Subject line`
- `Value proposition`
- `Trigger`

это `inputs` для модели

`Email` - это то, что модель должна сгенерировать
Т. е. стоит задача генерации текста на основании входящих `inputs`

Вопрос: какие существуют подходы для реализации этой задачи?

Я смотрю в сторону файн-тьюнинга моделей `GPT-2 / neo`. Но, эти модели принимают на вход просто полосу текста и что-то генерят. Мне же нужно, чтобы сгенерированный текст был релевантный входящим `inputs`.
Как можно это сделать?
Буду благодарен за любые советы в этом направлении

Comment: Что такое "фич"?

Comment: @edem это inputs